# How can I change the metadata of my songs all at once?

Tags: itunes, music, metadata

I have a bunch of songs for which I'd like to change the metadata (really just want to change capitalization for all of them). I'm not changing a field in all songs to one value, so selecting them all in iTunes won't work. They are AAC files. Is there an easy way to do this? Not having to download a third-party app would be nice, but I doubt it'll be that easy (maybe someone can prove me wrong :)).

Answer (score 3):

You could also run a script like this in AppleScript Editor:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    repeat with t in selection
        tell t
            set name to my titlecase(name)
            set artist to my titlecase(artist)
            set album to my titlecase(album)
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell

on titlecase(x)
    do shell script "ruby -rubygems -KUe 'require \"titlecase\"
    print ARGV[0].titlecase' -- " & quoted form of x
end titlecase
```

The titlecase gem can be installed with `sudo gem install titlecase`.

Answer (score 1):

So I've tried 3 ways to do this…

1. Writing my own little terminal script that goes through all the folders of the artists/albums/etc and auto capitalizes it (too complicated)
2. This handy little Automator trick I found online (I'm just gonna add the image tutorial here… 
   [image: Automator - How To]
3. This totally awesome (and the easiest of the three methods) I found online. Goto the following link :: 
   http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=titlecaps

Comment: +1 for Doug's script; I use it often when I rip CDs and the tags have bad capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

Capitalising each song title is not possible, but changing the common metadata among all of them works. For example, you can change the Album name and Album art for a number of songs.

There's an apple script that does specifically this (capitalise song name), but I haven't tried it yet: [iTunes Capitalizer](http://itunes-capitalizer.mac.findmysoft.com/).